# Robotframework POST multi object request

Tags: api, robotframework

I have a multi object request which look like follow in postman

```
{    "affordability": {
        "grossIncome": 100000,
        "netIncome": 80000,
        "capitalRequired": 25000,
        "groceries": 200,
        "utilities": 300,
        "savings": 400,
        "services": 500,
        "transport": 600,
        "support": 800,
        "housing": 700,
        "other": 900
    },
    "employment": {
        "sector": "CentralGovernmentSocial",
        "status": "Contract",
        "startDate": "2010-08-01",
        "endDate": "2030-08-01"
    },
    "declarations": {
        "debtLiability": "None",
        "pendingRetrenchment": "false",
        "knownMedicalCondition": "false"
    },
    "bank": "ABSA"
}
```

I am doing some automation on our API's and this one got me. I have struggled for quite some time to get the request to look like the postman request. I have managed to get that right.  Though I am not entirely sure if the method I went about to solve the problem is allowing for the POST request. Cause when I run the POST request I get the below error.
**HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:** this is a url

This is what my code looks like in:

```
#    &{baseURL}=          this is a url
#    ${offer}=           /offer
#    ${URL}=             Catenate           This is a url          ${appID}              /offer
#    log to console      ${URL}
#    Create Session      httpbin             this is a url
    &{affordability}=      Create Dictionary    grossIncome=60000     netIncome=30000      capitalRequired=25000       groceries=500        utilities=400     savings=300     services=200     transport=100     support=100       housing=500      other=100
    ${affordabilityobject}=    Catenate     {'affordability':      ${affordability}
#    log to console          ${affordabilityobject}
    &{employment}=       Create Dictionary      sector=CentralGovernmentSocial         status=Contract        startDate=2019-08-01           endDate=2023-08-01
    ${employmentobject}=        Catenate     'employment':      ${employment}
#    log to console          ${employmentobject}
    &{declarations}=      Create Dictionary     debtLiability=None      pendingRetrenchment=false      knownMedicalCondition=false
    ${declarationsobject}=      Catenate     'declarations':      ${declarations}
#    log to console          ${declarationsobject}
#    &{bank}=              Create Dictionary     bank=FirstNationalBank
    ${bank}=              Catenate     'bank':'FirstNationalBank'}
    log to console      ${bank}
    ${fullrequest}=             Catenate        SEPARATOR=,        ${affordabilityobject}      ${employmentobject}       ${declarationsobject}     ${bank}
    log to console      ${fullrequest}
    ${resp}=    Post      this is a url/${appID}/offer         json=${fullrequest}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Post Request Create Digital Offer
    Create Session          httpbin              this is a url
    &{affordability}=       Create Dictionary    grossIncome=${60000}     netIncome=${30000}      capitalRequired=${25000}       groceries=${500}        utilities=${400}     savings=${300}     services=${200}     transport=${100}     support=${100}      housing=${500}     other=${100}
    &{employment}=          Create Dictionary    sector=CentralGovernmentSocial         status=Contract        startDate=2019-08-01           endDate=2025-08-01
    &{declarations}=        Create Dictionary    debtLiability=None      pendingRetrenchment=false      knownMedicalCondition=false
    &{fullrequest}=         Create Dictionary    affordability=${affordability}      employment=${employment}       declarations=${declarations}     bank=ABSA
    ${CreateOffer_response}=       Post         this is a url/${appID}/offer          json=${fullrequest}
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${CreateOffer_response.status_code}     201
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Catenate for nested dicts,
You can use Create Dictionary like this :

Then, I'm not sure, but I think you need to transform the dict to json with :
${json_string}=    evaluate    json.dumps(${json})    json

```
&{baseURL}=         this is a url
${offer}=           /offer
${URL}=             Catenate             This is a url                     ${appID}                     /offer
log to console      ${URL}
Create Session      httpbin              this is a url
&{affordability}=    Create Dictionary    grossIncome=60000    netIncome=30000    capitalRequired=25000    groceries=500    utilities=400    savings=300    services=200    transport=100    support=100    housing=500    other=100
&{employment}=      Create Dictionary    sector=CentralGovernmentSocial    status=Contract              startDate=2019-08-01            endDate=2023-08-01
&{declarations}=    Create Dictionary    debtLiability=None                pendingRetrenchment=false    knownMedicalCondition=false
&{fullrequest}=     Create Dictionary    affordability=${affordability}    employment=${employment}     declarations=${declarations}    bank=FirstNationalBank
log to console      ${fullrequest}
${fullrequestJson}=     evaluate             json.dumps(${fullrequest})    json
${resp}=            Post                 this is a url/${appID}/offer      json=${fullrequestJson}
```

A better way to do it, is to store your json object in a separate file like "myjsonToPost.json" and you load it from file like this :

```
*** Settings ***
Library             JSONLibrary

*** Keywords ***
&{baseURL}=         this is a url
${offer}=           /offer
${URL}=             Catenate                  This is a url                                     ${appID}               /offer
log to console      ${URL}
Create Session      httpbin                   this is a url
${fullrequest}      Load Json From File       file_name=${EXECDIR}/path/to/myjsonToPost.json
# This method, without Library JSONLibrary
# ${fullrequestJson}     evaluate             json.dumps(${fullrequest})    json
# Or this one, with JSONLibrary
${fullrequestJson}      Convert String To Json    ${fullrequest}
${resp}             Post                      this is a url/${appID}/offer                      json=${fullrequestJson}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @flibidisch.
Hours after I posted this I figured it out. Though my solution looked bit different but it worked.